# How to program enc28j60 chip?

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, atmel

I recently got the enc28j60 module and I am stuck knowing nothing to do with it I read it is unprogrammable but when I looked in the datasheet it was just like any other mcu with registers and stuff and this clkout pin sth.. it has a prescaler that can divide so how can all that happen without it being programmed... and do I need the logic level shifter 3.3v-> 5v when I connect the enc28j60 to atmega32 even if I connect it with 5v power or don't I??

Comment: It is not clear what it is that you're asking.  The part datasheets shows that the enc28j60 is basically SPI to ethernet converter...  Once you talk SPI to it, you could configure the ECOCON register which controls the prescalar for CLKOUT.  Logic level shifting questions would better fit on electronics.stackexchange.com, however without a clearly stated question we're not likely to be able to help you there either...

Comment: Since the device is not programmable, the question is off-topic for SO. Your question belongs [here](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Nothing in the [data sheet](http://dlnmh9ip6v2uc.cloudfront.net/datasheets/BreakoutBoards/39662b.pdf) suggests that this device is an MCU.  Having *registers* or a *clock prescaler* does not imply an MCU or any software, the device may be entirely implemented in hard logic.

Even if there is an MCU at the core of this device, its software will exist in mask-ROM and will not be user programmable.

As the data sheet clearly describes, this module must be *connected to an MCU* to provide an Ethernet interface to that MCU.  On its own it will do nothing.

Comment: Regardless of *where* the code executes, a *program will need to be developed* to load values into those registers

Comment: yup i mean how to program its registers

Comment: @ChrisStratton : Yes, and it now seems that is what is being asked, though it is not clear that was understood from the original question.  The part about it being *"unprogrammable"* and *"just like any other mcu"* suggests a misunderstanding.

Comment: @ilouy : you should modify your question to ask what you really want to know.  Section 4 of the data sheet clearly shows how to communicate with the device and program the device registers via SPI, and section 3 describes those registers; so what is your question?